# Include PDF, XLS, DOC and other formats in SQL Report

Tags: sql-server, excel, pdf, reporting-services

we currently use SQL Server Reporting Services to create reports based on SQL data. We are at the moment able to include images coming from a varbinary(Max) column of a SQL database table. Now in those table several other formats are stored including PDF and MS Word and Excel documents. We would like to render a report including those documents at the end but we could not find any suggestions, especially for doc and xls format.

Is that possible? And if yes, how? 
Thanks for your help :)

Tom

Comment: Do you want to deploy the reports as doc and xls, or do you want to include doc and xls documents as attachments to the report?

Comment: The latter: I want to embed doc and xls and pdf in the reports (without any editing function) or attach them, so that the generated report has them at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same requirement in my project and the solution I see is preprocess those embedded documents, converting them to an images (per page in embedded documents). And then SSRS report itself will simply use image rendering control to embed those documents.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like iText can meet all your requirments http://itextpdf.com/

Comment: Hello James, thanks your advice. Unfortunately I don't see how iText meet my requirements? I need to embed PDF, Word and Excel files into a SQL Reporting Services report or - as you formulated it - attach it to the report. iText is not designed to export Word nor Excel documents to PDF, neither does it export PDF stored in a database to images (which is the only known way to me to embed external files into a report). Maybe I don't understand the full functionality of iText, or maybe you can help me?

Comment: I am not fluent in iText, but as I understand it if you create your report as PDF it should be able join all the elements, including the attachements together in a single PDF.

Comment: Oh, I'm creating reports in the first place with SQL Reporting Services by report builder. This report is then (by user) exported to PDF. But I want to include excel/word/pdf documents in the report already. (as pictures I guess)

Comment: @BISHD iText allows you to add any data as *attachment* as James proposed. That means that you have to click the attachment (its name in some list) to open it in an appropriate viewer which also needs to be on that computer, just like mail attachments work. If you instead want the contents of those documents displayed *in* the PDF, you need more than just iText; instead you need some tool which renders those files to something iText understands, i.e. bitmap images or some XML the iText XmlWorker can process.